# Clicking on a MenuItem, app keeps stopping

Tags: android, menuitem

I am trying to call new xml page when I click on any item in MenuItem, but it is crashing when I click on it, this is my code:
**MainAcivity**:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.generate_new) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityForItemOne.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.codes) {

        } else if (id == R.id.bills) {

        } else if (id == R.id.settings) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Activity which is called:

```
public class ActivityForItemOne extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    }
}
```

When I click on `Generate New` Item, it throws me out of the app. I think I am doing something wrong! 
Whats the problem?

Comment: please share your's crash stacktrace. Is `ActivityForItemOne` added in `AndroidManifest`?  Is `drawer_layout` id inside `activity_display_message` layout and is it `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: `activity_display_message` is simple xml without `DrawerLayout`, but let me check if I have added it in Manifest file...

Comment: @RadekJ I think I have not added it in Manifest File, but what should I write in there?

Comment: Whenever app crashes you can check your log output. In android studio just click logcat at the bottom. It should give you an idea about what happen in the app.

Comment: adding to manifest file worked, you can answer it below I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `ActivityForItemOne` added in `AndroidManifest`? Check if `drawer_layout` id inside `activity_display_message` layout and is it `DrawerLayout`?

Whenever app crashes you can check your log output. In android studio just click **logcat** at the bottom. It should give you an idea about what happen in the app.